# Request the url of a channel index

Tags: templating, entries, url, channels

How can I request the url for a channel index page from another page. I got this message asked on twitter towards craft, but they misunderstood my question.

The came back to me using craft.request.getSegment(x), but this will only work if I would like the index page of a channel when I'm on the entry page of this channel.

But how would I get the url for the "news" channel index page, when I'm in the "projects" channel section (either the index or an entry) of the site?

News is an entry-field of projects btw, so that we can show news related to a project on the site.

Comment: The channel index page or section landing page will be whatever you define it as in the channel's settings. If your channel is `news` then it will likely be simply `<a href='news'>...<a/>`. Is there something in your question that I am missing?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, this seems like a duplicate of [your previous question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4688/creating-a-related-content-subpage-to-a-channel-entry) then. Check out that answer and see if it doesn't answer this question also.

Comment: I don't think these questions are related, as the other one is about creating subpages.
This question is about requesting the slug from craft when I know the channel name, as these 2 obviously don't have to be related or have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no predefined 'index' page for channels. Channels are simply a collection of entries. If you want an index page then you will need to create it: either as a `single`, as an entry within another `structure`, or as a stand alone template in your templates directory (i.e. `craft/templates/news/index.html` or `craft/templates/news.html`). In any case, the url (or uri) is going to be whatever you have defined it as. (i.e. mysite.com/news/). See craft's [routing documentation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing) for more info on how requests are routed.