# Adding Navigation Menu

Tags: navigation

I am new to Craft.. 
I created the Entries but didn't understood how to setup them to display as a menu. Seen the documentation, templating references.. But not get any idea about how to add navigation menu for the entries type. I am using the default template.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are trying to create an 'index' page for your channel entries. There are a few ways to do this depending on the requirements of your site, but a very simple way is to create a 'single'. In the template for the single you can request the channel entries, and loop through the response to generate your index navigation.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('myChannelSectionHandle').limit(null) %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{entry.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you want the uri's to match up nicely then you can set the 'uri' of the single to be `mySectionName` and the 'uri' of the channel entries to be `mySectionName/{slug}` in the section settings — such that to the end user, it will simply feel like they are all part of the same section.

For some slightly more complex options, see these answers, [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4385/784) and [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6847/784).